# PHP Gmail Api Sending Message Links Being Removed

Tags: php, google-api, gmail-api

I am sending an email with the Gmail API and PHP. Yet, when I send the message all of the links inside of the message are getting stripped out. The HTML [p] and [div's] and [br's] tags are remaining but any links are being removed. Not sure why this is, here is my code:

```
    $objGMail = new \Google_Service_Gmail($client);
    $strRawMessage = "";
    $boundary = uniqid(rand(), true);
    $subjectCharset = $charset = 'utf-8';
    $strMailContent = $array['body'];
    $strRawMessage .= "\r\n--{$boundary}\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=' . $charset . "\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . "\r\n\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= $strMailContent . "\r\n";
    $mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($strRawMessage), '+/', '-_'), '=');
    $msg = new \Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
    $msg->setRaw($mime);
    $messageObj = $objGMail->users_messages->send("me", $msg);
```

The $array['body'] contents:

```
<a href="http://www.test.com" target="_blank">Test Site</a><br><br><br><br><div>My Signature<br>555-555-5555</div>
```

Here's the "Show Original" from my Gmail account:

```
Received: from 12312312312 named unknown by gmailapi.google.com with HTTPREST; Fri, 1 Dec 2017 08:29:20 -0800 To: Me   <myemail@gmail.com> From: Me   <myemail@gmail.com> Subject: Test Email Message MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary="asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf" Date: Fri, 1 Dec 2017 08:29:20 -0800 Message-Id: <asdfasdfasdfadsf=r_nHwnQF5LAtQ@mail.gmail.com>

--asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Test Site<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><div class"email-signature">My Signature<br>555-555-5555</div>

--asdfasdfasdfasdf--
```

Comment: It would probably help if you gave us an actual example of what `$array['body']` contains when it doesn't work right.

Comment: I've added the body, its very basic. When the email is sent, it all the tags remain except for any links.

Comment: Can you also show the email that was received on Gmail's end? If you click the drop-down to the top-right of an email, there's a "Show original" option. Should show all the headers and the HTML.

Comment: Just added the original contents...

Comment: That doesn't match the code you've shared. Gmail got something that says "Test Email Message". Your code shows "Test Site". Your second boundary looks truncated, too. I'd strongly suggest a class like SwiftMailer to construct the headers and multipart stuff rather than attempting to do it yourself...

Comment: I've been testing a lot of email. I just grabbed the first one of my many.